# Singleton Class: I was able to call private constructor multiple times when my main function was inside that singleton class

Tags: java, singleton

Please check out my code below.
My doubt is:
**Can there be a main method in java singleton class**
This will result in more than one object being created so this class does not follow the Singleton design pattern. Should it be considered bad practice to execute the main method in Singleton class?
Here is my code:

```
public class SingletonDemo {

private static int counter; //counter for number of objects
private static SingletonDemo obj;

private SingletonDemo() {
    System.out.println("Object number " + ++counter);
}

public static synchronized SingletonDemo getInstance() {
    if (obj == null) {
        obj = new SingletonDemo();
    } else {
        System.out.println("No new object created");
    }
    return obj;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SingletonDemo.getInstance();
    SingletonDemo.getInstance();
    SingletonDemo.getInstance();

    SingletonDemo obj1 = new SingletonDemo();
    SingletonDemo obj2 = new SingletonDemo();
    SingletonDemo obj3 = new SingletonDemo();
}
```

}

Comment: This will happen with any singleton class in Java and it doesn't really matter if it is the `main` method or some other member method. So I guess the only way you can prevent this from happening is do a check in the constructor. If there are more than one instances of this object, log a warning to the console and perhaps stick a breakpoint there to debug it easily.

Comment: There's no real problem with creating multiple instances - it can be useful for testing purposes. One alternative is to use the enum singleton idiom: `enum SingletonDemo { INSTANCE; }`. This guarantees a single instance. Or better, don't use singletons - preferable to use dependency injection.

Comment: Singleton class should not have a main method.  But yes if you put main inside a class, all the private members are accessible in the main method as well.